# "Cannot GET" on reverse proxy from Nginx to socket.io on express.js

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04?utm_source=Customerio&utm_medium=Email_Internal&utm_campaign=Email_nodeWelcome) to get Node.js working through Nginx on a two Ubuntu 14.04 servers via private networking (Node.js is on myappserver - accessible via private IP myprivatewebserver and publicly via mypublicappserver -  and Nginx on mywebserver). Everything works fine til this point - I can access a node.js application on myprivateappserver:3000 proxied via Nginx by going to http://mywebserver/node.

However, when I try and run up the [chat application](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) in socket.io on express.js, it works when I access it directly (http://mypublicappserver:3000) but, when I try and access it via my Nginx proxy (http://mywebserver/node), I get "Cannot GET /node" in the browser and in the firebug console "
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mywebserver/node".

If I curl http://myprivateappserver:3000 from mywebserver, I get index.html from my socket.io application fine.

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default contains:

```
location /node{
proxy_pass http://myprivateappserver:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

My index.js is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and my index.html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my first foray into nginx/node/express/socket (I'm normally an Apache/CakePHP person) so I may well be missing something very simple but would also be very grateful for any pointers on how to debug what's going wrong

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because SocketIO uses `/socket.io` path by default, so you need to configure Nginx so that it will proxy not only `/node` request, but `/socket.io` too:

```
location ~ ^/(node|socket\.io) {
    #your proxy directives
}
```

(By the way, it looks like you have typos: you wrote `proxypass`, but the correct form is `proxy_pass`. The same goes to other `proxy` directives)

You also need to perform one more edit in your NodeJS server file. Replace:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
```

with:

```
app.get('/node', function(req, res){
```

Now it should work.

This is not the only solution. You could also change [SocketIO path](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#path(v:string):server) with some changes in Nginx config, but the solution described above seems the simlest to me. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much @Curious. That would have taken me a long, long time to work out for myself - I hadn't understood how interlinked the proxied address was with the app it was proxying to. I've reinserted the underscores that were somehow removed from the proxy_pass, etc. directives when I pasted them in so as not to confuse others who arrive on this page. Thanks again.

Comment: @theotherdy you're welcome) there are various options of how to transform URL when proxying, you can read more [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). What about underscores - you've done a good thing but you've missed underscore in`$httpupgrade` variable. Good luck:)

Comment: I think I need to do some Nginx manual reading. Well spotted on that missing underscore - now added that one as well. Thanks again

Comment: In case anyone else follows this thread, what I have just spent most of the morning realising is that when, in my CakePHP application, which is being served from http://mywebserver, I try and set up a connection with: var socket = io('http://mywebserver/node'); this is proxied correctly and connects through to http://mypublicappserver:3000 BUT, although the connection is there, Socket.io thinks that I am saying that I want communication to be in the 'node' namespace so emits don't work! However change to: var nsp=io.of('/node') then nsp.on('connection', function(socket){etc. and it works!

Comment: Please help me as well.. I don't want get request to pass to my app.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574238/mongo-express-get-request-issue-with-nginx-proxy

Comment: Thanks for the working answer. BTW, if anyone gets "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" error after this solution try adding to nginx the following: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942#issuecomment-82352072

Comment: This helped me making the connection on http. But Https connection still doesnot work. Can you help me with that help ?

Answer (score 3):

Good aswer by Curious. I want to add that you don't have to adjust the node.js application if you use sub_filter. Your nginx must have been compiled with that module.

```
location ~ ^/(node|socket\.io) {
    #your proxy directives
    sub_filter /node /;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it will better if that:

```
location /node{
proxy_pass http://myprivateappserver:3000/; # add "/"
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

the proxy_pass add '/', then app.get('/') is alse ok!

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much, finally get it working... i just add this and disabled proxy checkmark in plesk:

location ~ / {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

Answer (score -1):

```
location ~ /(node|socket.io)  {
.......

}
```

This works also without " ^ " and " \ " signs.