# mongo-express get request issue with nginx proxy

Tags: express, nginx

I have mongo-express(mongodb admin UI) running at http://localhost:8081 on my ubuntu VPS. I wan to proxy it using nginx sever.

This works: 
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
}
```

xyz.com --> opens mongo-express admin page.

But this doesn't :(

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com;
    location /mongoadmin {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
}
```

More details:

xyz.com/mongoadmin --> shows "Cannot GET /mongoadmin/" in web browser.

The debug log on mongo-express on server is also logging a GET request (/mongoadmin/)

Comment: I found discussion here https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/146

Comment: You may also consider setting up mongoadmin on a subdomain, e.g. `http://mongoadmin.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add slashes in these lines:

```
location /mongoadmin/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
}
```

so that node server will treat everything after `/mongoadmin` as a root URL.

Comment: Thanks man... I've been strugling for half a day because I was missing these slashes...